# twitter link in ios opens twitter but nothing there to share

Tags: ios, twitter, share

I have a share-to-twitter link on a page to share a specific url. Everything works fine by sharing: title, image, description. Everything is shared correctly as I want to.

On Android devices the app starts and the twitter card is also shared.

On IOS (IPad, IPhone 7,8 - latest ios-Version) the app shows nothing to share. It only starts the app as if I only open it by clicking the app-icon on screen.

This is how my link looks like:

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://www.myPage.com?ref=abcd"><img src="../images/share_twitter.png"  class="imgShare"/></a>
```

Any hints for me?

thx ©a-x-i

Comment: I don't think it'll work like that for iOS, you might have to integrate its SDK if you want to do that. btw when you click on the link in iOS does it open the twitter app or browser?

Comment: I have added a class to my link: twitter-share-button. Now it opens the app, new tweet with my link. But it doesn't show my whole card with image. If I tweet it, delete tweet and tweet again, or if i validate the link on the developer side, the card is shown. I think it's because of my parameter, witch is unique for every user.